# Can I flash a custom fastboot mode image on a Samsung device to boot custom devices without tripping Knox

Tags: samsung, usb, external-sd, custom-roms, fastboot

I'm a noob and don't even know if these are seperate images, but I do know that Samsung has no fastboot mode as it is stuck entering it and instead has a download mode.

The question is, can I still put something there to boot, like coreboot, will it trip knox and will it be able to boot from sd card or an usb stick.

Comment: Even if it would be possible this would always trigger Knox. The bootloader software and it's state is part of the system state. What you want to do is not possible no matter how often you ask. If you want a separate OS buy a separate phone.

Comment: To flash custom image requires bootloader to be unlocked which trips Knox.

Comment: No sorry, now no one has to ask it anymore instead of me. I get it now, I only want to rule it out. It's awful to disgrace the environment throwing a device away because manufacturers make the freedom of the device disabled. You waste bluetooth, nfc, 4G LTE, Ram, SSD, display, glass, camera, microphone, USB and most important, the manufacturing of a battery. And please post it as an answer.

Comment: And otherwise you have to explain things more clear in your last comment.

Comment: it's common sense only official (OEM signed) firmware can be flashed on locked bootloader. this is for privacy security reasons. would you buy a smartphone where some hacker could just boot his own custom firmware on it? https://youtu.be/cTltHuEjTM8

Comment: You mean like booting Ubuntu touch? That's your freedom as a user! What are you talking about? Ofc I would buy a phone that could be revamped to anything you like! Anything to not trash another product by design.

Comment: It **is** not hackable at all **because** only OEM signed firmware can be flashed. no one can boot custom os/recovery like TWRP, by-pass lock screen and overcome encryption. locked bootloader is critical requirement for [Samsung Knox](https://www.samsungknox.com/en/secured-by-knox). data security is my right as a user. Ofc Ubuntu touch or anything else customized can be installed on **unlocked** bootloader. What are *you* talking about? ;)

Comment: If you want your data to be secure, then you might as well lock your phone recovery mode/ bootloader with a password, which you can't. If data security is really a right, why do phones stop receiving security updates (Also that's terrible for the environment)? If you want data security, you upgrade to the Ubuntu Linux kernel which will always provide more security over Android and it's security is open source.

Comment: You don't got the purpose of bootloader lock. there is no need to lock recovery (bootloader?) with password because you can't do nothing. recovery has no availbility to decrypt/mount userdata at all. Tell me one single Samsung device where custom recovery is available with encryption support? bootloader is cryptographically tamber protected and downgrade protected. What's the average nand flash lifetime before eMMC wear-out? Which Samsung Knox device does not receive security updates anymore? Did you even watched the Video about Samsung Knox? Why did you even buy Samsung and not Fairphone+3?

Comment: Which custom ROM/recovery do you want to boot from sd card? Is this custom ROM available for your device? Does this custom ROM support Samsung Knox? Why don't you want to trip knox?

Comment: All galaxy devices older than 5 years don't get security updates, so just can get thrown into the environment. Recovery has full permission to wipe your phone, so what does it matter what you do with the sd card. I don't wanna trip knox, so I can still have an unmodified native OS and some other android rom or ubuntu touch, or chromium os or openbsd on the other partition. I bought this Samsung because it has a good app experience for it price, it's waterproof unlike my last phone which besides also blocks the ability to update after customization and didn't even have a sd slot.

Comment: This becomes kinda pseudo arguing. There exist no other android or ubuntu touch. ChromiumOS is for google notebooks only and you will never run OpenBSD on smartphones. Anyway, 5 year old device can get thrown into environment (or [returned](https://closingtheloop.eu)) because of emmc wear-out, and Samsung is the only company that guarant security updates for 5 years. recovery has limited permissions, wiping data does not harm privacy security (and activates FRP). You are free to unlock bootloader and still have unmodified native OS. But you can't have Samsung Knox without it's fuse

Comment: You sound just like the government. Besides, I belief someone is able to invoke their own code to run entering fastboot mode in no-time, if they wanted.